# Mean of sample means from samples of different variances

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-error, multilevel-analysis

Suppose I have three samples $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma_b^2)$. I cannot measure the $x_i$ directly, so instead I estimate the value of each one by averaging $n_i$ draws from a distribution $\mathcal{N}(x_i, \sigma_{i}^2)$. Given these three estimates of $x_i$ with different sample variances, what is the maximum likelihood estimate of the population mean $\mu$, and how do I develop a CI around this estimate?